# GDI :Figure out which color the pixel has, which I drew before

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am trying to figure out which color the Pixel has which I drew before in red.

So as I read its not possible to do that directly, transformed my Graphics object to a Bitmap, which has the function GetPIxel and same width/height as my graphics object. Otherwise i think it would not function.

But it always returns me: Color [A=0, R=0, G=0, B=0]

Which i guess means White.

Here is my Code:

```
namespace GDi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
            this.Text = "Display At Startup";
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();
            this.Show();
            Pen BluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(BluePen, 0, 0, 50, 50);
            Pen RedPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

            dc.DrawEllipse(RedPen, 20, 70, 80, 0);
            dc.DrawEllipse(RedPen, 2, 88, 300, 0);
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(400, 400, dc);
            string test = myBitmap.GetPixel(2, 88).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesent works?

Comment: The `DrawEllipse` method takes the upper left and lower right points of the rectangle that bounds the ellipse.  You are looking at one of those corners which will not be on the ellipse.  Did you try (50, 50) which should be blue?

Comment: From MSDN about `Bitmap(int, int, Graphics)`: *"Initializes a new instance of the Bitmap class with the specified size and with **the resolution of the specified Graphics object**."* It only uses the DpiX and DpiY from the graphics object, it doesn't copy the image.

Comment: Change `this.CreateGraphics();` to `Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);` You try to get pixel from bitmap at the same time you're drawing on control (not on bitmap).

Comment: _I transformed my Graphics object to a Bitmap_  - No! That is an error: `Graphics` is only a tool to draw into associated `Bitmaps`, it __does not contain any graphics__! - Also: `Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();` this is usually wrong. Draw __only__ in the `Paint` event. Then you can use `DrawIntoBitmap` to get a copy of the current look and all the pixels that make it up!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the Bitmap constructor simply creates a new empty bitmap with no relation to your previous drawing.

You should probably use a different approach:

1. Create a Bitmap object like you've done
2. Create a Graphics object to draw in this bitmap using [Graphics.FromImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx) method
3. Draw into this new Graphics
4. When needed, read the pixel color you need from your bitmap
5. When the drawing is done, copy the bitmap to the form
6. Dispose your new Graphics and Bitmap objects. Alternatively, you may hold the Bitmap for a long time, but Graphics should better be created on each redraw.